# Incremenrtal load s3 folder files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

What is easy way to apply the incremental load in s3 folder files using python?
Date is taken from the "filename_180828_152153" like this!

I have tried insert the all filenames and dates to the table.And then compare maximum filenames compare with dates from the table.

But it was taken more time its like loading too much of time!

please advice?

Advance thanks.

Comment: Need to elaborate further on your S3 bucket and how the file grows. How many files got generated every day? Does the file itself keeps growing or once its uploaded it's never gonna be changed?

Comment: It was automated load Per day 3000 files added to the folder....Each day files added to the same folder that is the problem to load.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you want here is a Lambda function triggered by a S3 event notification. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

The idea is that whenever a new object is uploaded to your S3, it will trigger this Lambda function you define(e.g., do your ELT, cleanup and more...) This is more like a 'push' style workflow so that you don't need to worry about comparing.

An S3 event notification allows you to define a rule that filter on a prefix and/or a suffix of object name and add event trigger to them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Comment: A lambda could check the incoming file's name, and write it down to a well-known bucket. This may and likely will have a data race problem if several files are uploaded in parallel and complete nearly simultaneously.

Comment: Good point! Then I think you can always point the even trigger to a SQS queue. And make a cloudwatch event rule to periodically pull from that queue using a lambda. That way you have more control on the timing to trigger lambda.